# Blank page when using push() or setRoot() inside a service, Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using **Ionic 3** , and i have Some features that require the user is authenticated so when a user clicks on button, an alert is displayed. Since the features are all over the project, so I created a global function witch dispaly this alert, but when I put inside it **push()** or **setRoot()** , the project stop working and a blank page appears.

```
import { Injectable, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
//..............

@Injectable()
export class Alerts {
@ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
}

mustLogin() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'must login',
        message: 'go to login ?',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                handler: () => {
                    console.log('Cancel clicked');
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Login',
                handler: () => {
                   this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
                   //this.nav.push(LoginPage); blank page also
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    alert.present();
}
```

}

Comment: What is the error? Did you import `LoginPage`?

Comment: No error appears in the console , yes I did

Comment: Do you run your app in a browser, Android or iOS simulator?

Comment: I run it in  in a browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to follow below code.

You can read more [**about it here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) under the `Navigating from an Overlay Component` title.

```
constructor(private appCtrl: App){}
```

You need to **use**  `this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage);`

**instead** of this `this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);`

Comment: Thank you very much. This message appears in the console , can you tel me whet is the id of rootNav ? how can I use this method ?

`(getRootNav) is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Use getRootNavById instead.`

Comment: No info about it on their doc (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/). They also used the same way which I have mentioned in my post.

Answer (score -2):

This works fine for me:

```
import { NavController} from 'ionic-angular';  
constructor(public navController: NavController) {  
   this.navController = avController 
} 
this.navController.push(pageName,{param1:'param1', param2:'param2'});
```

or

```
this.navController.setRoot(pageName);
```